# CSS: How to set minimum and maximum height according to inside?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a table with 100vh height, how to set minimum height for `thead` according to inside and maximum `tbody`?

```
<table style="height: 100vh;">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: you can use min-height and max-height objects of css - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

*Updated*

*Did a few tests and noticed giving height to the body didn't work properly cross browser, which below update does (tested on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11)*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
table thead tr {
  height: 80px;      /*  on table elements, height works kind of like min-height  */
  background: yellow;
}
table tbody tr {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        HEAD<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        BODY
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Sevi Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the hack to achieve your goal. 
Use least height for thead, but not 0.Use 0% for tbody

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  }
table{
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
thead{
  background: red;
  height:1px;
}
tbody{
  background: blue;
  height:0%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>BODY</td>
        <td>BODY</td>
        <td>BODY</td>
        <td>BODY</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```